# TSQL Dynamic Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, pivot

I am using a select statement like this...

```
SELECT FileYear, FileSemester, StudentID, AssessmentCode, AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1, AssessResultsResult
FROM vStudentReportsSemesterResults
WHERE (FileYear = 2014) AND (FileSemester = 2) AND (assessmentCode LIKE '11%') AND (AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = 'Grade')
```

This gives me

```
FileYear  FileSemester   StudentID   assessmentCode   AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1  AssessResultsResult
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
2014        2             41965        11ENGADV        Ass1                       C
2014        2             41965        11ENGADV        Ass2                       C
2014        2             41965        11ENGADV        Ass3                       C
2014        2             41965        11ENGADV        Prelim                       
2014        2             41965        11HISANC        Ass1                       A
2014        2             41965        11HISANC        Ass2                       B
2014        2             41965        11HISANC        Ass3                       B
2014        2             41965        11HISANC        Prelim                       
2014        2             41965        11HISMOD        Ass1                       B
2014        2             41965        11HISMOD        Ass2                       B
2014        2             41965        11HISMOD        Ass3                       
2014        2             41965        11HISMOD        Prelim                       
2014        2             41965        11MATGEN        Ass1                       B
2014        2             41965        11MATGEN        Ass2                       
2014        2             41965        11MATGEN        Prelim                       
2014        2             41965        11PEDPDH        Ass1                       B
2014        2             41965        11PEDPDH        Ass2                       B
2014        2             41965        11PEDPDH        Ass3                       
2014        2             41965        11PEDPDH        Ass4                       
2014        2             41965        11PEDPDH        Prelim
```

I would like to dynamically pivot the data to give me something which looks like

```
FileYear  FileSemester  StudentID  AssessmentCode  Ass1  Ass2  Ass3  Ass4  Prelim 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014        2            41965       11ENGADV        C    C    C        
2014        2            41965       11HISANC        A    B    B        
2014        2            41965       11HISMOD        B    B    
2014        2            41965       11MATGEN        B    
2014        2            41965       11PEDPDH        B    B
```

Note that it has to be dynamic as the number of assessment points may change from subject to subject and year to year etc.

I have looked at information on this and tried to put together a dynamic pivot like

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1 
FROM vStudentReportsSemesterResults
WHERE (FileYear = 2014) AND (FileSemester = 2) AND (AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = 'Grade') AND (AssessmentCode LIKE '11%')) AS Courses


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'
SELECT FileYear,  FileSemester, StudentID, AssessmentCode, AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1, AssessResultsResult
FROM vStudentReportsSemesterResults
WHERE (FileYear = 2014) AND (FileSemester = 2) AND (AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = ''grade'') AND (AssessmentCode LIKE ''11%'')
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX(AssessResultsResult) 
          FOR AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1 IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

I keep getting error messages like

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.

I am assuming this is because of the quotation marks or the where statement syntax. I am getting a little frustrated and was just wondering if anyone could have a look at my code and tell me how I could dynamically pivot the data so that it gives the Grades in columns rather than in separate rows.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

## Update

Thanks so much for your help.

My code now looks like...

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1 
FROM vStudentReportsSemesterResults
WHERE (FileYear = 2014) AND (FileSemester = 2) AND (AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = 'Grade') AND (AssessmentCode LIKE '11%')) AS Courses

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'
SELECT 
FileYear,  
FileSemester, 
StudentID, 
AssessmentCode, 
AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1, 
AssessResultsResult
FROM (
SELECT * FROM vStudentReportsSemesterResults
WHERE (FileYear = 2014) 
    AND (FileSemester = 2) 
    AND (AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = ''grade'') 
    AND (AssessmentCode LIKE ''11%'')) src
PIVOT (MAX(AssessResultsResult) FOR AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1 IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS   PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

when I run this I get

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'AssessResultsResult'.
```

Obviously it is not recognizing the fields for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks marc_s for editing this. I had some images but I have not used this site much and don't have enough reputation points to add them. This looks a lot better.

Comment: I moved your edit to your question, because it belongs here. You shouldn't edit answers from other users, unless you want to correct them. If you want to respond, you should either write a comment, or update your question.

Comment: Thanks Leonid. Still learning...

Comment: Thanks Tomasito for your code below. Works well but it still doesn't put all the data in one row. For each Grade even if it is the same assessment code, it is in a new row. I want everything for the one assessmentcode on the same row. Is this possible?

Comment: Also, I want to have more than just a student's ID in the row. I would like the Student ID, then the assessment code, then the FileYear and FileSemester, then all the data starting with Ass 1. With the code provided, if I try to add the Assessment Code it is put in the first column and wipes out the other data. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT StudentID, '+@ColumnName+'
FROM (
SELECT * FROM vStudentReportsSemesterResults
WHERE (FileYear = 2014) 
    AND (FileSemester = 2) 
    AND (AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = ''grade'') 
    AND (AssessmentCode LIKE ''11%'')) src
PIVOT (MAX(AssessResultsResult) FOR AssessAreaHdgAbbrev1 IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable
```

Generaly: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT foo) AS Foo PIVOT ...`

Look at documentation for [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;

GO
SELECT VendorID, [250] AS Emp1, [251] AS Emp2, [256] AS Emp3, [257] AS Emp4, [260] AS Emp5
FROM 
(SELECT PurchaseOrderID, EmployeeID, VendorID
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader) AS p
PIVOT
(
COUNT (PurchaseOrderID)
FOR EmployeeID IN
( [250], [251], [256], [257], [260] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY VendorID;
```